# C++ specific variable to a general one

Tags: c++, variables

My current **working** code:

```
void GraphicFunctions::drawECM(const OpenGLCamera& camera)
{
   gl->drawECMEdges(camera, ecm, layerID);
}
```

OpenGL class:

```
void OpenGL::draw(const OpenGLCamera& camera)
{
   const vector<double>& cameraBBox = camera.getBoundingBox();
}
```

---

Is it possible to make "OpenGLCamera" more general, make it into a pointer or something?
For example something like this:

```
void GraphicFunctions::drawECM(const OpenGLCamera& camera)
{
   const int* camerapointer = camera;
   gl->drawECMEdges(camerapointer, ecm, layerID);
}
```

OpenGL class:

```
void OpenGL::draw(const int& camera)
{
   const vector<double>& cameraBBox = camera->getBoundingBox();
}
```

This way i will be able to use other camera types as well...!

Comment: erm, *inheritance* - have you not heard about this concept?

Comment: Read about inheritance and virtual member functions.

Comment: please read topics on inheritance and polymorphism with a focus on c++ (ie http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/ and http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/ )

Comment: Don't pay too much attention to cplusplus.com - it's not very good. [The "canonical" SO C++ Book & Guide List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) has plenty of good things.

Comment: but how can i put inheritance into a function, i mean, into variables i know how to do it... but how to chance it so that a function is "typeless" or "changeable"??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use inheritance to add different camera types. This will also work if you pass them by reference

```
struct Camera1 : public OpenGLCamera
{
  // reimplement something
}
struct Camera2 : public OpenGLCamera
{
}
```

now you can pass them to `OpenGL::draw(const OpenGLCamera& camera)`

Comment: but how can i put inheritance into a function, i mean, into variables i know how to do it... but how to chance it so that a function is "typeless" or "changeable"??

Comment: No you don't do that. You should really read something from the stuff suggested in the comments

Comment: But this way i still need another function/method for another type of camera... right? 
Since i want to use multiple types of cameras...!
OpenGLCamera, UnityCamera, Direct3DCamera (all different types..) 
so then OpenGL::draw(const SomeTypeOfCamera& camera) wont work...
This way i can only use OpenGLCameras or do i see that wrong?

Comment: you define which methods are common for every camera you use. Then have a base class for those. Then reimplement them for each derived class you have